# Pull information from a web table into excel

Tags: html, asp.net, excel, vba, html-table

In a follow up from this question ([Open IE and Interact with Web Form using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701521/open-ie-and-interact-with-web-form-using-excel-vba/52701600?noredirect=1#comment92330320_52701600))…

With the help of user QHarr, I now have excel interacting with the web form, and submitting the correct information to bring up the table required.

Now what I need is for excel to be able to read that web page, find the table, and extract the data into a separate tab within the spreadsheet... and I have no clue where to start in order to make it do this?

The HTML of the page is below, and I believe it is an ASP page that takes the information submitted to generate the correct table of information...

```
<!--include file="../../Connections/SQLStore_00103_DT_Performance_Packs.asp" -->
<!--include file="../../Connections/SQL.asp" -->


<!--include file="JSClass/FusionCharts.asp" -->
<script language="JavaScript" src="JSClass/FusionCharts.js"></script>

<!--include file="Includes/SaveCookies.asp" -->




<br>





<body>

</body>
</html>




<link href="../CSS/KPI_Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Store Performance Report</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style49 {font-size: 7pt}
.style50 {font-size: 16pt; color: #FF9933; }
.style60 {font-size: 12pt}
-->
</style>
</head>




<body >


<!--include file="../Store_Performance/Includes/Disable_copying.asp" -->

<style type="text2/css">
<!--
.style45 {font-size: 12px}
-->
</style>

<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' width='95%'><tr  class='formtextsmall'><td class='border9' rowspan='2' valign='bottom' align='center' class='formtextsmall'><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=1'class='vert'></a></td><td class='border9' colspan='5' valign='bottom' align='center'   bgcolor='#fff762' >Sales</td><td class='border9' colspan='3' valign='bottom' align='center'    ></td><td class='border9' colspan='3' valign='bottom' align='center'  bgcolor='#fe7845'  ></td><td class='border8' colspan='15' valign='bottom' align='center'  bgcolor='#76df64' ></td></tr><tr class='formtextsmall'><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap  bgcolor='#fff762' ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=2' class='vert'> £&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=3' class='vert'>% to Tgt&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=4' class='vert'>No</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=5' class='vert'>1&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=6' class='vert'>2&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=50' class='vert'>3&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=51' class='vert'>4&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=44' class='vert'>5&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap  bgcolor='#fe7845'  ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=7' class='vert'>6&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=8' class='vert'>7&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=9' class='vert'>8&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap   bgcolor='#76df64'><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=55' class='vert'>&nbsp;9&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap   bgcolor='#76df64'><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=43' class='vert'>Total Retention&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#CCFFFF'  ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=41' class='vert'>Comp Retention&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#CCFFFF'  ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=12' class='vert'>Comp R&S SR %&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#CCFFFF'  ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=14' class='vert'>Tablet R&S SR %&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#CCFFFF'  ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=22' class='vert'>Anti Virus SR %&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#CCFFFF'  ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=16' class='vert'>Cloud SR %&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#CCFFFF'  ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=18' class='vert'>Setup SR%&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#CCFFFF'  ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=20' class='vert'>Office SR%&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#FFCCFF' ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=42' class='vert' >Other Retention&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#FFCCFF' ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=26' class='vert'>MDA R&S  SR%&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#FFCCFF' ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=24' class='vert'>Vision R&S  SR%&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#FFCCFF' ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=28' class='vert'>Other R&S  SR%&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border3' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#FFCCFF' ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=35' class='vert'>Bracket/Stand/AV SR%&nbsp;</a></td><td class='border14' valign='bottom' align='center' nowrap bgcolor='#FFCCFF' ><a href='Summary_Page_Sum.asp?ranking=30' class='vert'>Premium Cable SR%&nbsp;</a></td></tr>

<tr class='formtextsmall'><td class='border3' align='left'  class='text'>&nbsp;(427) John R</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'   bgcolor='#fff762' >-£60&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>&nbsp;1&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>£0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>£0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text' bgcolor='#fe7845'  >&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>-£7&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>-£7&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='center' class='text'   bgcolor='#76df64'>&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'   bgcolor='#76df64'>&nbsp;88.9%&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'  bgcolor='#CCFFFF'  >&nbsp;100.0%&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text' bgcolor='#CCFFFF'  >&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text' bgcolor='#CCFFFF'  >&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text' bgcolor='#CCFFFF'  >&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text' bgcolor='#CCFFFF'  >&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text' bgcolor='#FFCCFF' >&nbsp;85.7%&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td><td class='border3' align='right' class='text'>&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td><td class='border14' align='right' class='text'>&nbsp;0.0&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class='formtextsmall'><td align='center' class='border11' colSpan='35'>&nbsp;</td></tr></table><br>
<!--include file="Includes/League_Page_Links.asp"-->
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
-->
</style>
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
  <td valign="bottom" bgcolor="#001446"><div align="right" class="xbig style1 style1">A</div></td> 

  </tr>
</table>






</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can assist me in developing the code to pull the data from the entire table (which only has 1 row in the example but can have anywhere up to 150 rows total) I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a standard write out table by looping rows and columns. The following assumes you are using IE and have the IE.document fully loaded. There was only one table shown in your excerpt.

```
Dim html As New HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable, c As Long, r As Long, tr As Object, tc As Object

Set hTable = IE.document.querySelector("table") '<== get the table

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each tr In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr") '<== get the rows and loop over them
        r = r + 1: c = 1 
        For Each tc In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")  '<== get the columns within a row and loop over them
            .Cells(r, c).Value = tc.innerText
            c = c + 1
        Next
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Did you try this?